Restoring BizTalk Server
We have to configure BizTalk environment that will be replica of our current production environment, the one way to do this could be export the msi and binding files from production and import. Is there any other way to do this, like by export and importing the backups of BizTalk databases?

Exporting the MSI and importing them is usually the way to go.
If you clone the DB, you will also have to clone the BizTalk Application server, as it will have the DLLs GACed.  There are other gotcha's as well when cloning a BizTalk environment.  You would have to follow the steps in How to Move the BizTalk Server Databases.  Note: The server would have to be in the same domain, as Migrating BizTalk Servers from one domain to another domain isn't supported.
Even after following the database move steps, sometimes there are still some configurtion settings in the BizTalk database that haven't updated correctly.  Doing a text search for the old SQL server name an updating it manually usually fixes it.

thanks for the quick response, could you please advice on below if this could be a workaround.
1- Create new BizTalk Sever application with SQL server both on same VM
2- Restore production databases backup to the newly created SQL server
3- Update database server name in these databases to point them new DB server
4- Configure BizTalk Server using "join the existing BizTalk group" option
5- Install Application's MSIs and GAC external assemblies.

@kamal Updated the answer with some more info
